# SOQL nested query on object related to parent?

Tags: soql, nested

I have a query on `CampaignMember` and I would like to get some `Tasks` for the `Contact` or `Account` that is associated with the `CampaignMember` record. I'm guessing I can't do that since the `Tasks` relationship is between `Task` and `Contact`, not with `CampaignMember`. Unfortunately I can't do this with Apex as I am producing a Conga Composer document and am limited to SOQL inside Conga Queries.

When I make the `Contact` the root of the query I can do this (obviously, since there is a `Tasks` relationship between the `Contact` and `Task`) but then I can't pull in the `Tasks` for the `Accounts`, or any fields really since the `CampaignMember` records with `Accounts` are excluded.

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    FirstName,
    LastName, 
    (SELECT 
        Id,  
        Account.Name 
    FROM CampaignMembers
    WHERE CampaignId = '1234567890ABCDEFG'),
    (SELECT 
        Id,
        Who.Name
    FROM 
        Tasks
    WHERE Status = 'Not Started'
)
FROM Contact
WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ContactId 
        FROM CampaignMember
        WHERE CampaignId = '1234567890ABCDEFG'
    )
```

What would be cool is if I could do something like this (I know I can't):

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    ContactId,
    Contact.FirstName, 
    Contact.LastName, 
    Account.Name,
    (
        SELECT 
            Id,
            Who.Name
        FROM 
            Contacts.Tasks
        WHERE Status = 'Not Started'            
    ),
    (
        SELECT 
            Id,
            Who.Name
        FROM 
            Accounts.Tasks
        WHERE Status = 'Not Started'            
    )
FROM CampaignMember
WHERE CampaignId = '1234567890ABCDEFG'
```

but clearly I can't since there is no `Task` relationship to `Account`. Are there any ways that I can query objects that are related to a record that is related to the root object of my query?

I'm required to build a document that handles `Accounts` and `Contacts` together, hence why I went the `Campaign` route as I can add both objects to a `Campaign`.

Comment: Maybe you could duplicate the data into a unified table to make the merge work...awkward set of requirements for sure.

Comment: is this Conga Composer document by any chance a spreadsheet?

Comment: @cropredy, it is in a Word document (I'm using lots of conditional fields). I'm not opposed to a spreadsheet but since there was lots of formatting I felt Word was more appropriate.

Comment: so -- I had this issue a few years back. I used a multi-tab spreadsheet wherein each tab did one SOQL Conga query and then using excel automation, I could generate client-side the merge of results into a new tab.  As I recall, I used PowerBI

Comment: I certainly could do this with some VLOOKUPS in Excel, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the outline of a solution that I used many years ago when faced with a similar issue

- Make your delivery document a spreadsheet rather than a document
- Add three tabs to the spreadsheet: Summary, Query1, Query2 - you may need additional helper tabs
- On the Query1 tab, bind this to the first Conga query
- On the Query2 tab, bind this to the second Conga query
- Make the Summary tab the default tab when the spreadsheet is opened by the user
- Use formulas on the Summary tab to join the two other tables in tabs Query1, Query2 to get the result intended. You may need a helper tab for pivot tables to assist

Basically, you are using client-side logic that can execute when the spreadsheet is opened by the user to join the data and present in a form suitable for the end user.

The practical details of the spreadsheet formulas can be addressed with assistance from the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site and other Excel-oriented sites.  I used Microsoft's add-in PowerBI to make this task easier.